# Android.mk No such file or directory

Tags: android-ndk

I used NDK to design an app.but I got a problem.

> andriod\MyApplication2\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\Android.mk:
>   No such file or directory

in the `setup-toolchain.mk.`like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93XpN.jpg)

But I check

```
\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\
Android.mk
```

is here.
like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzczx.jpg)

How can I solve this problem? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Whoa, where did you get the idea to structure your project like this? Android.mk should go under app/src/main/jni. Check out the [Google NDK samples repository](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/android-mk) to see some properly structured projects. The [hello-jni](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/android-mk/hello-jni) example is a great one to start with.